# how to I have two .war files within one .ear file?

Tags: java, jboss, war, ear

I use jboss 4.0.2 and i want to have two .war files within one .ear file .

Comment: @Vinegar: Because multiple WARs within a single EAR is common practice?

Comment: @skaffman: Sorry lack of experience. ;P

Answer (score 10):

I would have thought this was self-evident from the structure of the EAR's application.xml file, but here's an example of how it looks with two WARs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>/directory/of/war1</web-uri>
      <context-root>/war1</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>/directory/of/war2</web-uri>
      <context-root>/war2</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```