# Adding Grails Project and Java web project to EAR project

Tags: grails, websphere

I want to create a EAR project by adding a Grails 2.5.4 project and a Java web project to it. It will be deployed to WAS 8.5.5 server. The idea is to share sessions between these two apps using session context sharing of WAS. Pl. let me know if this is possible. As of now , the EAR identifies the grails app as a JAR only and hence it does not explode on deployment in WAS. I am using GGTS for this and have integrated WAS developer tools/WAS runtime in the IDE

Comment: Grails - silly me.  I'll retract.  Edit your question, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create EAR project and Java Web Project through GGTS and then add the Web Project to the EAR. Then your generated application.xml will have one entry for web module like this:

```
<module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>TestWeb.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>TestWeb</context-root>
    </web>
</module>
```

Then add the entry for grails application. Your modified application.xml will have now two entries:

```
<module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>TestWeb.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>TestWeb</context-root>
    </web>
</module>
<module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>TestGrails.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>TestGrails</context-root>
    </web>
</module>
```

Export the ear file and add the grails war file(created after building the project) using common zip utilities as given in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355974/how-to-add-a-war-file-into-an-existent-ear-file) question. Then the ear file can be deployed in WAS.