# how to create ear file, and include war and jar files inside that

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am trying to create an EAR file from the command prompt. I have used

```
jar -cvf myServletWAR.ear .
```

But my question is, how can I get this EAR file to have WAR files and JAR files inside it?

Do I need to create the war file separately and include in the ear file?

I can't use the ANT file for this, as there are few restrictions on this project.

Comment: Do you use maven or Eclipse IDE for development?

Comment: Try copying all the files (i.e. jars, wars, application.xml, etc.) into some directory (e.g. ~/temp/build_ear), and then use the same command you listed above, that should work. If you need a one liner, you can your bash script.

Comment: is that is possible with java ???

Answer (score 9):

One of my EAR files has structure as follows:

```
app.ear
  - APP-INF
    - lib
      // libraries (.jar) here
  - META-INF
    - MANIFEST.MF
    - weblogic-application.xml
  - module1.war
  - customlib.jar
```

This archive is being deployed onto WebLogic 10.3.

Remeber .ear is just a ZIP file, so you can always create it this way, although it seems messy.

Answer (score 8):

check if jar cmd is working if so, create the jar of your class files and descriptors etc.

After that `jar -cvf <<earname>> <<files want to be in the ear >>`

Answer (score 4):

Could you try this :

```
jar -xvf myServletWAR.ear
```

You could also refer to :

[How to add a WAR file into an existent EAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355974/how-to-add-a-war-file-into-an-existent-ear-file) and [how to I have two .war files within one .ear file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220891/how-to-i-have-two-war-files-within-one-ear-file)

You would have to add these EAR file references in the application.xml of the ear file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have generated a client and EJB together, they are automatically packaged into an enterprise archive file (.ear) and you do not need to do this. Otherwise:

- Package the EJB's .jar file into an .ear for your application. To do
  this use a jar command similar to the following:

> ```
> jar -cvf myApplication .ear myService.jar
> ```

If you have a client .war file you can add that to the .ear file in the same way.

- Create a deployment descriptor application.xml either using your
  application server's tools or by copying and editing a sample, as
  follows:
- Locate a sample .ear, which is in examples directory in

> ```
> mapdemo/mapdemo/repos/myService.deploy/JMapServ-WL.ear
> ```

- Extract the descriptor application.xml from the .ear file, using the following jar command:

> jar -xvf JMapServ-WL.ear META-INF/application.xml

- Make a copy of the application.xml descriptor and edit it, replacing JMapServ with the name of your .jar file. You can also add the name of your .war file if you added that to the .ear file.
- Put the descriptor in the meta-inf subdirectory of the directory containing your .ear file.
- Package the descriptor into your .ear file using a jar command similar to:

> ```
> jar -uvf myService.ear META-INF/application.xml
> ```

Comment: Just curious about if you quote the answer direclty from this link https://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2FGUID-0E0191D8-C39A-44D1-BA4C-D67107BAF784%2FHHADTHDPOY10.html? If yes, it's encouraged to also put the origin.

Answer (score 0):

`.jar` file into an `.ear`

```
jar -cvf myApplication.ear myService.jar
```

`.war` file you can add that to the `.ear` file in the same way.

Refer http://supportline.microfocus.com/Documentation/books/sx51/thdpoy10.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an ear from the command line, following are the options that you can try.

Option 1. Using an ant build and use the ear task. Configure this ear task as stated in [stackoverflow question on ant ear task usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267300/how-do-i-create-an-ear-file-with-an-ant-build-including-certain-files)

Note: Maven based build is preferred over ant these days.

Option 2. If you can use maven, [configure your modules and use maven ear plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-archetype-plugin-1.0-alpha-7/examples/j2ee-simple.html) to generate an ear. The below command will be able to generate the ear.

```
mvn clean package
```

Refer to the maven question regarding a Java EE project for more [information on configuring war, jars for an ear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134894/maven2-best-practice-for-enterprise-project-ear-file).

Comment: What do you mean? Are you asking whether ear creation can be done using 'java jar' command? If so, yes. But people normally use maven build for creating a ear.